# What is the reason for command not recognized error message on executing my batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have written this batch code:

```
@echo on
set variable=z
set t=%time:~0,2%
IF %t% LSS 12 (
        %z%=_1
    ) ELSE (
        %z%=_2
)
```

And when run the batch file from command window, I get this error:

> IF 14 LSS 12 (_1)  ELSE (_2)
>   '_2' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Where is the mistake in my code resulting in this error message?

Comment: this is because there's no variable `z` and when expanded it becomes empty.`=` is a delimiter and the script tries to execute `_2`.Probably you want `%variable%=_1`  ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve. I guess you want to check the condition `%t%<12` and set your variable z to _1 if this is the case and to _2 otherwise.

Your error is that `%z%=_1` is not a valide statement. To assign a value to a variable you always have to use `SET`:

`SET z=_1` will result in %z% holding the value _1. So your code can be fixed like this:

```
@echo on
set variable=z
set t=%time:~0,2%
IF %t% LSS 12 (
        SET z=_1
    ) ELSE (
        SET z=_2
)
```

Based on the rest of your code you also might need to add the line `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` at the beginning of your code and access your variable z as `!z!` instead of `%z%` below your IF-construct.

EDIT:

To fit your desctiprion from your comment you should do this:

```
@echo on
set t=%time:~0,2%
IF %t% LSS 12 (
        SET z=_1
    ) ELSE (
        SET z=_2
)
set folderName=%date%%z%
mkdir %folderName%
```

An easier way would be to set `folderName` inside the IF-counstruct:

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set t=%time:~0,2%
IF %t% LSS 12 (
        set folderName=%date%_1
    ) ELSE (
        set folderName=%date%_2
)

mkdir !folderName!
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.I'll try to explain the main idea.
When I'm creating directory I'm using built-in function %date% but i want to know if the directory was created before 12 am or after that hour.
I want to add _1 or _2 like suffix when creating directory i.e. - 10.11.2015_1 or 10.11.2015_2.

Comment: Well I managed something like that:
@echo off

set t=%time:~0,2%
set dt=%date%

IF %t% LSS 12 (
  SET dt=%date%_1
 ) ELSE (
  SET dt=%date%_2
 )
set xdir=LocalDir
cd %xdir%
md %dt%
cd %dt%
xcopy  RemoteDir /Y /H /S

set zdir=LocalDir
cd %zdir%
md %dt%
cd %dt%
xcopy RemoteDir /Y /H /S
pause

Comment: Thanks for your time.